# Blurring a PGM image with C

Tags: c

I'm working on a project that involves processing and transforming a PGM image. So far, everything has been working fine but when I got to the blurring something weird happened and I don't know what's wrong with it.
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaH1u.png)
[blurred image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVxUB.png)

It seems like a part of the image got flipped to the right side, which I don't know if it's because of the logic or the saving process.

```
for (x =0; x < blurred->height ; x++) {
    for (y =0; y < blurred->width ; y++) {
        counter = 0;
        sum = 0;
        average=0;
        // check lower left pixel
        if ((x + 1) < blurred->height  && (y - 1)>= 0){
            sum += blurred->data[x+1][y-1];
            counter++;
        }
        // check right pixel
        if ((y + 1) <  blurred->width ){
            sum += blurred->data[x][y+1];
            counter++;
        }
        // check lower right pixel
        if ((x + 1) < blurred->height && (y + 1) < blurred->width){
            sum += blurred->data[x+1][y+1];
            counter++;
        }
        // check lower pixel
        if ((x + 1) < blurred->height ){
            sum += blurred->data[x+1][y];
            counter++;
        }
        // check left pixel
        if ((y - 1) >= 0){
            sum += blurred->data[x][y-1];
            counter++;
        }
        // check upper pixel
        if ((x - 1) >= 0){
            sum += blurred->data[x-1][y];
            counter++;
        }
        // check upper left pixel
        if ((x - 1) >= 0 && (y - 1) >= 0){
            sum += blurred->data[x-1][y-1];
            counter++;
        }
        // check upper right pixel
        if ((x - 1) >= 0 && (y + 1) < blurred->width ){
            sum += blurred->data[x-1][y+1];
            counter++;
        }
        // index pixel 
        sum += blurred->data[x][y];
        counter++;
        average = sum / counter;
        final->data[x][y] = average;
    }
}
```

This is my save method:

```
void save(image * pgm, const char * filename)
{
    int i, j, rows, cols;
    FILE * writeFile = fopen(filename, "wb");
    rows = pgm->height;
    cols = pgm->width;
    fprintf(writeFile, "P5\n");
    fprintf(writeFile, "%d %d\n", cols, rows);
    fprintf(writeFile, "255\n");
    fprintf(writeFile, "\n");
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            
            putc(pgm->data[i][j], writeFile);
        }
        
    }
    fprintf(writeFile, "\n");
    fclose(writeFile);
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't your loop running out of bounds at multiple places? That would be an undefined behaviour.  For instance `if ((y + 1) <  blurred->width ){` here . Maybe you could add a 1px padding with pixel replication and try again or run your loops from `1 to bound - 1` in both x and y direction.

Comment: I tried what you said but nothing changed., or maybe something pixels did change but not enough to be able to notice. Also, when I tried my program on other images, none of them have this issue. So I don't know if it's my code or the image itself.

Comment: Are these other "working" images of the same size as this "non-working" one?

Comment: They're of different sizes.

Comment: In your save method, you address data [y][x], but in your origianl function, you address it [x][y]

Comment: Given the [format specification](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html), I think that both `fprintf(writeFile, "\n");` lines shouldn't be there. Are you sure that the height and width of both the images (in the unshown `image` struct) are the same?